# what are the parameters for fire select event in openui5 tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

Hi i am using openui5 tree.by default first my first node to be selected.
for that i would like to use fireSelect event of tree.
what are the parameters to be pass for fireSelect?

```
var oData = {
                root:{
                    name: "root",
                    0: {
                        name: "item1",
                        0: {
                            name: "subitem1",
                            0: {
                                name: "subsubitem1"
                            },
                            1: {
                                name: "subsubitem2"
                            }
                        },
                        1: {
                            name: "subitem2",
                            0: {
                                name: "subsubitem3"
                            }
                        }

                    },
                    1:{
                        name: "item2",
                        0: {
                            name: "subitem3"
                        }
                    }

                }
        };
          var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
          // set the data to the model
          oModel.setData(oData);

          var oTree = new sap.ui.commons.Tree("tree");
          oTree.setWidth("100%");
          // set the model to the tree
          oTree.setModel(oModel);

          var oTreeNodeTemplate = new sap.ui.commons.TreeNode("node");
          oTreeNodeTemplate.bindProperty("text", "name");
          oTreeNodeTemplate.setExpanded(true);

          oTree.bindAggregation("nodes", "/root", oTreeNodeTemplate);
//oTree.fireSelect(item1,/root/1);

          oTree.placeAt("body");
```

here item1 to be selected by default.and then user can select any node.

i am using this as dropdown box which contains hierarchical options.
is it possible to add filter for tree nodes?

here my exmple https://jsbin.com/gekazarife/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select first node of `Tree` invoke [`setIsSelected`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.TreeNode.html#setIsSelected) on a first node of tree.

```
oTree.getNodes()[0].setIsSelected(true);
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/lixoze/edit?js,output)